# Delete all files and folder

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I want to delete all files and folders inside one folder.

#### Code

```
If Not Directory.Exists(txtTXT.Text) Then
     Return
End If

Dim files() As String
files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(txtTXT.Text)

For Each element As String In files
    If (Not Directory.Exists(element)) Then
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(txtTXT.Text, Path.GetFileName(element)))
    End If
Next
```

My code only deletes the files, but not the folders... How can I delete all?

Comment: Don't use .Exists() like that. The file system is volatile, so by the time you act on the result it's already out of date. Just handle the exception instead.

Comment: thank you, i revise my program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revised my program, so I used this code..

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory( _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\epubcount", _
    FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn this code into a function.  Make a recursive call to the function when you encounter a directory, passing the directory name to it.  The function should also delete the directory that was passed in.